# Нужно ли экранировать переменную при передаче в header?

Tags: php

```
header('Location: '.$_GET['url']);
```

Безопасно ли передавать $_GET['url'] напрямую или нужно что то делать?

???

Comment: Да, Нет. Вопрос можно закрывать!

Comment: так да или нет?

Comment: Начиная с версии php 4.4.2 можно ничего не делать. С php.net  
> 4.4.2 and 5.1.2  This function now prevents more than one header to be sent at once as a protection against header injection attacks.
Хотя, если у Вас в адресной строке находится идентификатор сессии пользователя, то можно подсмотреть его в referer и тем самым зайти на сайт под залогиненым пользователем, если нет дополнительной защиты.

Answer (score 1):

Единственное что можно сделать это `urlencode()` что бы не возникло проблем с допустимыми символами, в остальном опстности нет

Answer (score 1):

вот написал так (на всякий случай), может кому пригодится

```
header('Location: '.str_replace("\r","",str_replace("\n","",str_replace('&amp;','&',htmlspecialchars($_GET['url'], ENT_QUOTES)))));
```

Comment: почитайте регулярки, там нет ни чего сложного. Это сократит и запись и время работы скрипта